# How to place 2d array with different lengths in Google Sheets Script?

Tags: google-sheets

I'm sending 2d array to google sheets using json:

```
{"rep":[["a3289035","b656011929551"],["brown","realistic","yellow"]]}
```

Then I'm getting this array in google script:

```
var parsedJson = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents);
var repList = parsedJson.rep;
```

And everything is ok, but when I'm trying to place this array on the sheet:

```
sheet.getRange(row + 1, 2, repList[0].length, 1).setValues(repList[0]);
sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3, repList[1].length, 1).setValues(repList[1]);
```

I'm getting the error:

> Cannot convert Array to Object[][]

What is wrong?

I found that this code can do it:

```
repList[0] = repList[0].map(function(e){return [e];});
repList[1] = repList[1].map(function(e){return [e];});

sheet.getRange(row + 1, 2, repList[0].length, 1).setValues(repList[0]);
sheet.getRange(row + 1, 3, repList[1].length, 1).setValues(repList[1]);
```

but how to make it work for 2d array with any lengths and any subarray's lengths?

Expected result:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Vosnim,

Try something like this:

```
var repList = parsedJson.rep;
var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('TEST')
var startCol = 1;
repList.forEach(function (r, i) {
var values = r.map(function (ro) { return [ro]});
sheet.getRange(1, startCol + i, values.length, 1).setValues(values)
})
```

Comment: thank you. I tried your code and it shows the same error.

Comment: My bad. Edited my answer.

Comment: As it currently is, the output of the first .setValues() will be partly overwritten by the second .setValues().

Comment: @JPY, it works, but not in the way I wanted. It stores each array in a line, but I 'd like to place each subarray in different column.

Comment: thank you, but it's not working. No errors, but nothing written. I'm not sure that I understand what you mean by 'flatten' (or transpose?): https://playcode.io/192884?tabs=console&script.js&output

Comment: Flatten the 2D-array to a 1D-array and then wrap in square brackets, thus creating a 2D-array with a single row. If you need more help, please share a copy of your spreadsheet and show us your expected outcome.

Comment: thank you for your help. I found my mistake, now your latest code works but it writes whole flattened array in one row (B1:F1) = a3289035; b656011929551; brown; realistic; yellow

Comment: Yes, that's correct. That's what I thought you wanted. Please clarify what you want to achieve with the output.

Comment: I updated the post with the picture of expected output.